# PowerShell script that switch between Foms authentication and Windows authentication IIS

Tags: powershell, authentication, iis

I got power shell script that create IIS web/pool.By default web site is Form auth i wanna switch it to windows auth from ps script.Found how to do that but form auth dont disable and my both form and win auth are enable and this is a problem.How to disable form auth so i can have only windows auth?

Answer (score 0):

To enable windows and disable forms auth:

```
$config = (Get-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication "IIS:\sites\$iisAppName")
$config.mode = "Windows"
$config | Set-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication -name enabled -value true -PSPath IIS:\ -location $iisAppName/$iisAppPoolName
```

To disable windows and enable forms:

```
$config = (Get-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication "IIS:\sites\$iisAppName")
$config.mode = "Forms"
$config | Set-WebConfiguration system.web/authentication

$winAuth = Get-WebConfiguration -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication
$winAuth.enabled = $false
$winAuth | set-Webconfiguration -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication -PSPath IIS:\ -location "$iisAppName"
```